# How does mongoose handle fields not in the schema for existing documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that doesn't allow a `metadata` field. But I go in and manually edit a document and add a `metadata` field.

How will mongoose handle this when I save this document programmatically in the future? Will it strip the `metadata` field? Is it possible to change/remove that field programmatically (even though it's not in the schema)?

Comment: it'll strip that field and not allow it to store in MongoDB. But if you try to store it using Mongo shell, it will store the `metadata` without any error.

Comment: Yes you can still change/remove that field if the schema has the `strict` option set to `false`.